# Spring Boot Missing Plugin when Running from Command Line

Tags: java, linux, maven, spring-boot

I have a maven project that I can run in Eclipse, but I can't get it to run from the linux command line.  I get an error when I run 'mvn spring-boot:run':

"No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories"

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>


  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                  <arguments>
                      <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                  </arguments>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure you launch the command from the directory where this pom is located?

Comment: I didn't know I should until I ended up trying the full command "mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run", which made the error change to telling me I need to run the command from the POM directory.  Which I tried, but now I'm getting yet a third error. This is fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the full command "mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run", which worked for some reason when I ran it from the directory containing the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your application from the jar instead? If you are using Spring Boot's maven plugin as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html), you should be able to just `java -jar your-jar-file.jar`, no need to use maven.